# Проблема при работе с MySQL

Tags: mysql

Проблема при работе с mysql. Когда пытаюсь создать базу пишет следующее:

```
Error
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE  `highfive_users`.`system_users` (

`id_position` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`name` TINYTEXT NOT NULL ,
`pass` TINYTEXT NOT NULL ,
`fio` TINYTEXT NOT NULL ,
`fiodir` TINYTEXT NOT NULL ,
`phone` TINYTEXT NOT NULL ,
`email` TINYTEXT NOT NULL ,
`block` ENUM NOT NULL ,
`dateregister` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
`lastvisit` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `id_position` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

MySQL said:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL, `dateregister` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `lastvisit' at line 1 `
```

Что я не правильно делаю?

Comment: вроде как сам решил проблему. Ошибся при заполнении полей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет возможности сейчас проверить, но

- `ENUM` варианты данных перечислить не пробовали?
- не уверен в возможности использования `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` с данными типа `DATETIME`